# Does SQL Alchemy know the current Sequence value?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, sequence

I'm using SQL Alchemy (1.0) ORM with a PostgreSQL database. Let's say I have a line in my class

```
serialid = Column(Integer, Sequence('journal_seq'), unique=True)
```

I realize that then there is a special "table" in my database, that holds the current value of the last one or next available integer for a serialid. Can I, from ORM, get the value of that integer (without incrementing it - otherwise I can just call next_value)? And is there a guarantee that the next serialid will have exactly that value?

I'd like to make an journal item with a serialid, and also make another item refering to that same serialid, but I'd like two of those to be committed (or rollbacked) together - and until I commit the journal item, I don't know what its serialid is. Maybe there is a cleaner way of doing it without knowing the current sequence value. A `relationship` would be great, but I don't know how to set it up.

(I know there is a question that asks the same thing when you control the SQL directly. I'd like to do the same from SQL Alchemy ORM.)

Comment: The usual (SQL) approach to this is: get the next sequence value for the journal, insert the journal item using that id, insert the other rows using that id, then commit. Alternatively: insert the journal item, then use `currval()` when inserting the "other" rows which will then use the generated id without you having to query it first.

Comment: It's great to know that it's the SQL-idiomatic way, that hopefully means SQL Alchemy ORM supports it. I just need to find out how. :-)